# I am finding it difficult to initialize package.json file in my truffle project

Tags: solidity, package.json, truffle

I can not install package.json dependencies in my truffle project and I have tried touch.json. it's giving me errors. I have also tried truffle init, but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

to install `package.json` dependencies you have to type `npm install` or `npm i`

Comment: I got it using npm init --y